# Badged list control for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, list, controls

Does any of you know of a lightweight list control for ASP.Net where I could add badged items on a horizontal line? Something like this:
[image]

Comment: You can use http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ for multiple select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RadAutoCompleteBox which has the complete functions I needed.
Thanks Telerik.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/autocompletebox/overview

Edit: Added reference to **Telerik for ASP.Net** and sample code:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="KeywordsAutoComplete"
Width="100%" OnLoad="KeywordsAutoComplete_Load" OnClientEntryAdding="restrictDuplicateEntry"
EmptyMessage="Type keywords..."
CssClass="autocompletebox control transition-025"
AllowCustomEntry="true" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Restrict Duplicate Entry
    function restrictDuplicateEntry(sender, eventArgs) {
                var entries = sender.get_entries(),
                count = entries.get_count();

                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {           
                    if (entries.getEntry(i).get_text() == eventArgs.get_entry().get_text())
                    {
                        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```

C#:

```
protected void KeywordsAutoComplete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt; // Binding Data (For Lookup)
    KeywordsAutoComplete.DataSource = dt;
    KeywordsAutoComplete.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You have to show code here not just put link in comment. It is ok you are answer tick back and put it in your own answer.

Comment: I've just added an example.

Comment: How can do it for Win forms?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like

```js
function addMore()
{
   $("div").append("<span>New Badge</span>");
}
```

```css
span{

background-color:#7F7F7F;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>jQuery</span>
  <span>ajax</span>
  <span>c#</span>
  <span>Html</span>
  <span>Java</span>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="addMore();" value=" + ">
```

Use asp.net `Literal` control that will result you in `span`.