# Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox duplicate selection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In RadAutoCompleteBox i am able to select same item multiple times, how can i avoid selecting same item multiple times. That way it allows the user to duplicate items selected.
for example

I will select Apple. It goes to the box.Next again i will select apple.Then i get 2 apples on the box.
Now apple is selected 2 times, this is a problem.

How to avoid this?

I am using the below link

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/autocompletebox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Would be good to share your code and links to demos you've checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of questions. 
i solved Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox duplicate selection issue.

the OnClientEntryAdding property of Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox solve duplicate issue.

i used this in my code
OnClientEntryAdding="restrictDuplicateEntry"

and solved duplicate selection issue in Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox.

Answer (score 2):

This is code for "restrictDuplicateEntry" function:

```
  function restrictDuplicateEntry(sender, eventArgs) {
            var entries = sender.get_entries(),
            count = entries.get_count();

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {           
                if (entries.getEntry(i).get_text() == eventArgs.get_entry().get_text())
                {
                    eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

It's from: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587077/badged-list-control-for-asp-net)